# How to give xib cell button action in HomeVC in swift

Tags: swift, button, action, cell, xib

I have created xib collectionview cell.. and i am able to use all its values in HomeVC like below

```
class HomeVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

@IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

 override func viewDidLoad() {

super.viewDidLoad()
let nib = UINib(nibName: "MainCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)
collectionView.registerNib(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MainCollectionViewCell")

 }

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MainCollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MainCollectionViewCell

 cell.arrivingLabel.text = indexData.arriv
 cell.lblDiscountedPrice.text = indexData.discPrice

 
return cell
}
```

like below i can give action to xib cell button, **but i want xib cell button action in `HomeVC` class** how, please guide me here

```
   cell.btnDetails.addTarget(self, action: #selector(connected(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

   @objc func connected(sender: UIButton){
  }
```

**i want like this in HomeVC**

```
 @IBAction func productDetailsMain(_ sender: UIButton){
  }
```

**note**: if i use same collectionview cell then if i drag from HomeVC button action outlet to collectionview cell button then its adding.. but if i use xib cell in collectionview then this process is not working.. how to give xib cell button action in HomeVC class

Answer (score 0):

You have to use closure.

cell class add this property

```
var connectionButtonAction: (() -> Void)?
```

and on the button action make this

```
@objc func connected(sender: UIButton){
    connectionButtonAction?()
  }
```

so finally for on the cell creation you have add this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MainCollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MainCollectionViewCell

 cell.arrivingLabel.text = indexData.arriv
 cell.lblDiscountedPrice.text = indexData.discPrice

 
cell.connectionButtonAction = { [weak self] in
   print("cell button pressed")
}
return cell
}
```

I think this is the simple way, but also you get the same approach using delegates.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the collection view cell's button trigger an action in the view controller that own's the collection view, you need to add the view controller as the target. You can do that in your cellForItemAtIndexPath, but you will need to remove the previous target/action so you don't keep adding a new target/action each time you reuse a cell:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MainCollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MainCollectionViewCell

    cell.arrivingLabel.text = indexData.arriv
    cell.lblDiscountedPrice.text = indexData.discPrice
    // Remove the previous target/action, if any
    cell.btnDetails.removeTarget(nil, action: nil,for: .allEvents)
    // Add a new target/action pointing to the method `productDetailsMain(_:)`
    cell.btnDetails.addTarget(self, action: #selector(productDetailsMain(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    return cell
}
```

You could also set up your cells to hold a closure as in luffy_064's answer.

Note that if you are running on iOS 14 or later, you can use the new `addAction(_:for:)` method of UIControl to add a `UIAction` to your button. (UIActions include a closure.)

That might look like this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MainCollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MainCollectionViewCell

    cell.arrivingLabel.text = indexData.arriv
    cell.lblDiscountedPrice.text = indexData.discPrice
    // Remove the previous target/action, if any
        let identifier = UIAction.Identifier("button")

    removeAction(identifiedBy: identifier, for: .allEvents)
    // Add a new UIAction to the button for this cell
    let action = UIAction(title: "", image: nil, identifier: identifier, discoverabilityTitle: nil, attributes: [], state: .on) { (action) in
            print("You tapped button \(indexPath.row)")
            // Your action code here
        }
    cell(action, for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: i want cell's button action in viewcontroller class, how?

Comment: like this `@IBAction func productDetailsMain(_ sender: UIButton){
  }`

Comment: My answer explained that. In your view controller class, assign the target/action to the button in your cellForItemAtIndexPath method. (But be sure to remove previous target/action assignments so you don't keep adding more, and call your IBAction method multiple times for each button tap.)